# Typescript promise help needed

Tags: typescript, promise, amazon-ecs, pulumi

I'm new to typescript and nodejs but need to do some fix on the typescript code.

I need to run an ECS one-off task using Pulumi, and I have documentation on how we should run the task from taskDefinition
https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/awsx/ecs/#EC2TaskDefinition-run

But without description in words, I cannot understand how should I call this `run` action

`public run: (params: RunTaskRequest) => Promise<awssdk.ECS.Types.RunTaskResponse>;`

There is an example on how to run this with api-gateway, but it's not clear to me how to call this `run` as standalone action https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/aws/ecs/#running-fire-and-forget-tasks

Appreciate any advice on this!

UPD:
More detailed block of code that I have:

```
const kafkaTask = new awsx.ecs.FargateTaskDefinition("kafka1-task-efs", {
    vpc: vpcSelected,
    containers: {
        kafkaTask: {
            image: imageKafkaTaskEfs,
            logConfiguration: {
                logDriver: "awslogs",
                options: {
                    "awslogs-group": "ecs-kafka1",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "kafka1-task-efs"
                }
            },
            mountPoints: [
                {containerPath: "/mnt/kafka/data", sourceVolume: "kafka-data"},
                {containerPath: "/mnt/kafka/secrets", sourceVolume: "kafka-secrets"},
                {containerPath: "/mnt/zookeeper/log", sourceVolume: "zookeeper-log"},
                {containerPath: "/mnt/zookeeper/data", sourceVolume: "zookeeper-data"}
            ]
        }
    },
    volumes: [
        {name: "kafka-data", efsVolumeConfiguration: {rootDirectory: "/kafka-data", fileSystemId: fsKafka.id}},
        {
            name: "kafka-secrets",
            efsVolumeConfiguration: {rootDirectory: "/kafka-secrets", fileSystemId: fsKafka.id}
        },
        {
            name: "zookeeper-log",
            efsVolumeConfiguration: {rootDirectory: "/zookeeper-log", fileSystemId: fsKafka.id}
        },
        {
            name: "zookeeper-data",
            efsVolumeConfiguration: {rootDirectory: "/zookeeper-data", fileSystemId: fsKafka.id}
        }
    ]
});

kafkaTask.run({ cluster }).then(res => console.log(res));
```

UPD2: Here is the error I ended up having:, but not sure it can be useful:

```
error: Running program '/pulumi/main-infrastructure' failed with an unhandled exception:
Error: Cannot call '.get' during update or preview.
To manipulate the value of this Output, use '.apply' instead.
    at Proxy.get (/pulumi/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/output.js:172:15)
    at FargateTaskDefinition.run (/pulumi/node_modules/@pulumi/ecs/taskDefinition.ts:226:39)
    at /pulumi/main-infrastructure/index.ts:127:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/pulumi/main-infrastructure/index.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
error: update failed
```

Comment: Just to understand where the problem might be. Are you comfortable with promises, or are they new to you?

Comment: Also, is this a brand new task definition, or do you just want to run a predefined ECS task? The latter is more straightforward.

Comment: @RichardDunn I've updated the description with more details.
Promises is a new conept to me
I've added the exception that I have to the details as well

Comment: I think you need to create a Service before you can run the task, see [createService](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/awsx/ecs/#FargateTaskDefinition-createService). You can also create [the service](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/awsx/ecs/#FargateService) separately and pass the task definition as a parameter. Either way, they both have to be defined and reference each other. I've only created ECS containers on EC2 servers, where you can run a task without a service, but I think you're required to create a Service for Fargate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where you're having the problem, but according to those docs you need to create an instance of `EC2TaskDefinition`, so you'll need something along the lines of:

```js
const task_def = new EC2TaskDefinition('', {}, {})

task_def.run({})
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Obviously there's some parameters missing, but I'm not even sure if you've created a class instance from your question, if it's the parameters that are the problem then comment and I can try expand on those a little.